# How to save data with association in gorm golang?

Tags: go, go-gorm

So, I want to save the movies and movie_genres data, but it always fails, which is stored in the database is the movies table as much as looping movie_genres, and the movie_genres column with the wrong movies ID. This is the result

**movies table**
[image]

**movie_genres table**
[image]

**This the JSON result from frontend**

```
{
   "title":"Qui aut consectetur",
   "release_date":"1974-11-25",
   "runtime":"91",
   "mpaa_rating":"PG",
   "rating":"2",
   "description":
   "Anim dolor molestias",
   "genre_id":["1","2"]
}
```

---

Below is my code on go

**models**

```
type Movie struct {
    ID          int          `json:"id"`
    Title       string       `json:"title"`
    Description string       `json:"description"`
    Year        int          `json:"year"`
    ReleaseDate time.Time    `json:"release_date"`
    Runtime     int          `json:"runtime"`
    Rating      int          `json:"rating"`
    MPAARating  string       `json:"mpaa_rating"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time    `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time    `json:"updated_at"`
    Genres      []Genre      `json:"genres" gorm:"many2many:movie_genres"`
    MovieGenre  []MovieGenre `json:"movie_genres" gorm:"many2many:movie_genres"`
}

type Genre struct {
    ID        int       `json:"id"`
    GenreName string    `json:"name"`
    Movies    []Movie   `json:"movies" gorm:"many2many:movie_genres"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
}

type MovieGenre struct {
    ID        int       `json:"id"`
    MovieID   int       `json:"movie_id"`
    Movie     Movie     `gorm:"foreignKey:MovieID"`
    GenreID   int       `json:"genre_id"`
    Genre     Genre     `gorm:"foreignKey:GenreID"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
}
```

**handler.go**

```
func (app *Application) CreateMovies(ctx *gin.Context) {

    var payload web.MoviePayloadResponse
    if err := ctx.BindJSON(&payload); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    var movieGenre models.MovieGenre

    movieGenre.Movie.ID, _ = strconv.Atoi(payload.ID)
    movieGenre.Movie.Title = payload.Title
    movieGenre.Movie.Description = payload.Description
    movieGenre.Movie.ReleaseDate, _ = time.Parse("2006-01-02", payload.ReleaseDate)
    movieGenre.Movie.Year = movieGenre.Movie.ReleaseDate.Year()
    movieGenre.Movie.Runtime, _ = strconv.Atoi(payload.Runtime)
    movieGenre.Movie.Rating, _ = strconv.Atoi(payload.Rating)
    movieGenre.Movie.MPAARating = payload.MPAARating
    movieGenre.Movie.CreatedAt = time.Now()
    movieGenre.Movie.UpdatedAt = time.Now()
    
    movieGenre.ID, _ = strconv.Atoi(payload.ID)
    movieGenre.MovieID = movieGenre.Movie.ID
    movieGenre.CreatedAt = time.Now()
    movieGenre.UpdatedAt = time.Now()

    err := app.models.Repository.CreateMovie(movieGenre.Movie)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    
    for _, v := range payload.GenreID {
        movieGenre.GenreID, _ = strconv.Atoi(v)
        err := app.models.Repository.CreateMovieGenres(movieGenre)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, &gin.H{
        "ok": "response",
    })

    return
}
```

**repository.go**

```
func (MovieRepositoryImpl *MovieRepositoryImpl) CreateMovie(movie Movie) error {
    MovieRepositoryImpl.DB.Create(&movie)
    return nil
}

func (MovieRepositoryImpl *MovieRepositoryImpl) CreateMovieGenres(movieGenre MovieGenre) error {
    MovieRepositoryImpl.DB.Create(&movieGenre)
    return nil
}
```

**payload**

```
type MoviePayloadResponse struct {
    ID          string   `json:"id"`
    Title       string   `json:"title"`
    Description string   `json:"description"`
    Year        string   `json:"year"`
    ReleaseDate string   `json:"release_date"`
    Runtime     string   `json:"runtime"`
    Rating      string   `json:"rating"`
    MPAARating  string   `json:"mpaa_rating"`
    GenreID     []string `json:"genre_id"`
    CreatedAt   string   `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   string   `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

The results that I expect are in the movies table, only 1 column is made, and in the movie_genres table store data movies as much as the genre inputted with the new movies ID. How to solve the problem?

Comment: the request does not contain `id` and there doesn't seem any way to uniquely identify row within the table all the columns which are being used contain same data except for the genre which is different based on which the last column are selected matching the criteria.

Comment: ok, I've tried fetching the last movie data with `movie, _ := db.Last(&movie).Error` but how to get the `id` from `movie`?

Comment: movie is of `Movie` type which has `ID` attribute which can be used to get `ID`

Comment: yeah I know, but when I type Like thi `movie.ID` it's error and no namespace in vscode

Comment: you have written this line `movie, _ := db.Last(&movie).Error` in wrong way it would only return error since you are accessing `Error` remove movie from this line and then tried debug print the movie variable

Comment: yeahh it's wrork, Thank you!!!